# Fastest spatial index for 2D data, once built there are no updates

Tags: c#, algorithm, indexing, geospatial, spatial

- I have large 2D object collection, only lines for now.
- I need algorithm suggestion how to create fastest spatial index over
  this collection so that I can collect all objects that are inside some
  bounds.
- Once built index will not be updated.
- Object distribution in this database is not spatially uniform.
- Algorithm implementation in C#.
- Update: Current usage is for road graph of some country, so lines are small, from one crossroad to another, bigger density in populated areas. I think this gives good picture about data.

Obviously there are many indexing methods to achieve this, but I would require one that is fastest.

Comment: What do you want to build the index for ?

Comment: As I said, I have many lines in 2D space, I need to access all lines is some bounds very often, so algorithm must be fast. I will store this index in memory while program is running and hold pointers on objects which are indexed.

Comment: Is there a lot of overlap? can you provide a representative picture?

Comment: See update, I have no picture, but exact usage can give you very good image of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)** if you want to save 2-D lines and your queries are 2-D range queries.

The algorithmic complexity of a query is O( log^2 N ).

Answer (score 1):

Check out quadtrees.... and DotSpatial for spatial type handling, including a  quadtree implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). There's a C# implementation available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cspatialindexrt/.

R-trees should have the kind of performance of a Segment Tree and the above implementation should be stand alone and fairly independent of a lot of extra code references, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet on this. It depends on the type of data (i.e., only points, only lines, triangles, meshes, any combination of them, etc.) and the type of query (point inside polygon, line intersection, nearest neighbors, any geometry inside a circle or box, etc).

You have a datastructure designed for specific type of query and data. If you want to use a single datastructure for all types of queries and all type of data you have to trade off either space or time or both. You can approach to be reasonably fast but you won't be optimal in general.

In my experience, a datastructure general enough to cope with most geometrical objects and can handle several types of queries I would recommend the AABB-Tree:

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html